# What is the proper way to dispose avalonia bitmap?

Tags: c#, bitmap, dispose, propertychanged, avaloniaui

Iam using the [Avalonia](https://avaloniaui.net/) UI Framework to build a dotnet core MVVM app.
I want to display frames from a WebCam and created a simple WebCamViewModel:

```cs
    public class WebCamViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Bitmap webCamImage;

        public Bitmap WebCamImage
        {
            get { return webCamImage; }
            private set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref webCamImage, value); }
        }

        public WebCamViewModel(WebCamImageService webcamImageService)
        {
            webcamImageService.OnFrame += BitmapReceived;            
        }

        public void BitmapReceived(Bitmap bitmap)
        {    
            WebCamImage = bitmap;
        }
    }
```

I tried the naiv approach and dispose the old bitmap like this:

```cs
public void BitmapReceived(Bitmap bitmap)
        {    
            if (webCamImage != null) webCamImage.Dispose();
            WebCamImage = bitmap;
        }
```

I get System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." while resizing the application. [StackTrace](https://pastebin.com/raw/aYvXn4n1)

1. How can I properly dispose the old bitmap instances so that the GC doesn't have much to do?
2. Is there a better approach to display dynamic changing image content?

Comment: You have a potential memory leak - you did not unsubscribe from OnFrame event. For disposing use Dispose interface when object not needed anymore.

Comment: The `BitMap` is exposed as a property. What might read from that property? What else might have a reference to that `BitMap` that will suddenly stop working if it is disposed? In order to safely dispose this you must know what else has a reference to that object.

Comment: @ScottHannen actually this property is only used via data binding in the view

Comment: @eocron Thanks for pointing that out. I intended to use the OnFrame event for the whole application life time.

Comment: Bitmaps should be ref-counted internally, so it should be safe to dispose the user-facing Bitmap class as long as you no longer expose the disposed bitmap as a property.

Do you have a stack trace for that exception?

Comment: @kekekeks yes i updated the initial post

Comment: According to the stack trace the bitmap is still bound to the `Image` control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a couple of question exist:

1. OnFrame event should be unsubscribed, regardless if you use it per-application or per-something else. This is just a good practise, like for example 'use using on disposable entities', if you by chance create multiple windows, or want to switch between multiple windows at zero cost or whatever happens. So this is a must:

```
public void Dispose()
{
     _service.OnFrame -= BitmapReceived;
}
```

2. If bitmap is **public** accessable property - someone can reference it, be it DataBind or whatever AND unintentially using code MUST handle its lifetime - invoke Close/Dispose/Finish/or whatever. This invalid approach in UI will lead to problems where you should count references to this instance to manage it's death (And you will also encounter accidental NRE and other exception across app which you should just omit). Instead, just create an event, in which disposing of this entity will be performed by user. This will render this property useless and you don't need any dispose:

```
public event EventHandler<Bitmap> OnFrame
{
    add
    {
        _service.OnFrame += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        _service.OnFrame -= value;
    }
}
```

This way you can perform required transformations on Bitmap before you feed it to View. This is why you choose **MVVM** in first place: view after transformation of model, transform before commiting to model. It will probably be a good idea to switch to **MVC** for web cam experience instead.

Comment: 1.) Thanks, i did change that.

2.) Maybe I expressed myself wrong: I get a sawtooth-like memory pattern during the GC run, which I wanted to avoid by disposing of the image itself. This seems to be counterproductive, since (as kekekeks emphasized) the image is still bound.